Is DMA (Direct Memory Access) interrupt maskable?
My textbook states that DMA will interrupt the CPU once a batch of data is swapped to memory. However, it didn't tell me whether the DMA interrupt is maskable. Is it maskable?

Of all the interrupt controllers I have used (either onboard with the CPU or an external controller) have maskable interrupts.  Some CPUs support a nonmaskable interrupt (NMI) which is, by definition, not maskable.  I have neither seen nor heard of a DMA interrupt that was not maskable.
